# Is there a best practice for redirecting users in a web application during an interaction?

Tags: forms, gui-design, design-patterns

To be more clear, my scenario is something like this:

User interacts with a dynamic form that might or not create a new record on the system. When this record is created, I want to give the user the option to go to the newly created record. The customer, however, asked for them to be automatically redirected.

I'm arguing that the user might not necessarily want or need to work on this new record right away, so giving him the option would be the best approach, with a link that would do the redirect instead. The last flow screen would then show a message like "You created a new record. You can work in this record or keep working on this one instead."

Is there any article about this kind of interaction?

Comment: Unless it's 100% of users that want to go to the newly created record, do not automatically redirect them.

If your form is inside a modal, just give them two small buttons after they've filled the form, e.g "Stay on this record" and "Work on the new record", you may emphasize the button you want users to click more often. Obviously use shorter, better button labels :) 

If it's not a modal, just append a link/button below the form asking if they'd like to work on the new record.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @DennisNovac. Is that something that is just common sense or there's some writing about this? Would love to have some reference for this.

Comment: Is it an option to have two actions when submitting the new record, something like "Save" and "Save and View" (not great wording, I know)

Comment: I believe it is. The user does not need (logically speaking) to work on the newly created record. It is up to the business to tell them what to do in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Do research. Don't do what the customer wants, try to understand why he/she needs that and map the flow. Check the pain points, reiterate wireframes and test it again. Don't listen only to one customer/user, I encourage you to explore more the problem with at least 10 customers/users.

**Why:**

I think there are some questions you need to answer here before finding the best solution:

1. Do you need to save that data?
2. What happens with the data that the user has inserted when you send them to a different path?

Maybe try creating a separation between the actions of creating the list and the exploration part where the user can explore this list